# Finding entire function satisfying $f'(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Problem: Determine whether there exists an entire function $f$ such that $f'(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{n}f(\frac{1}{n})$ for every positive integer $n$. If there does exist such an $f$, is it unique?

Attempt at solution: it seems that there does exist such a function $f$, namely $f(z) = 0, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$. However, I am having a hard time seeing if this is actually the only entire function that satisfies the property. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $f$ is entire, so is $g(z)=f'(z)-zf(z)$. The condition implies that $g(1/n)=0$ for all $n$. Since $1/n$ accumulates at $z=0$, we must have $g(z)=0$ for all $z$. Therefore $f$ satisfies the differential equation $$f'(z)=zf(z)$$

We can have $f\equiv 0$. If not, we can use separation of variables

$$(\ln(f(z))'=z$$

Which gives $f(z)=\exp(z^2/2+C)$

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you.

Comment: Appealing to the logarithm for complex valued functions may cause problems. To solve $$f'(z)=zf(z)$$ rather consider $$g(z)=f(z)e^{-z^2/2}$$ and check that $$g'(z)=0$$ hence indeed, $$f(z)=Ke^{z^2/2}$$

Comment: @Did Ah thank you, was concerned about that.